Can't find -lpython311 when compilling C++ file
Im trying to use Python in C++ but when I try running with the button on vscode nothing happens.
Full code:
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <python3.11\Python.h>



int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello C++ from Python')");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

I then tried to run using the terminal by using:
g++ RunFile.cpp -o output -L C:\Python311\libs -lpython311 -I C:\Python311\include
but this error occurs :
cannot find -lpython311: No such file or directory collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
I then tried switching -lpython311 with -lpython3 but this occurs:
undefined reference to PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'`
I tried chaging python311 to python3 but the PyRun_SimpleStringFlags didn't work
I use Windows 11 and python 11
I am a beginner.
Thank you for your time.

Each version of Python generally requires you to use a specific Visual Studio version.  I don't believe Python ships with libraries that are compatible with gcc.

it may need to find correct location of libpython311.a. So you may try to use function find on your system to get it. But as I remember command python3-config --includes can get this path.

you may also check linker's flask - python3-config --ldflag it also should show what you need in -L to add folder with `libpython311.a

BTW: on linux it needs -lpython3.11 with dot in 3.11 so maybe on Windows it also needs with dot. On Linux command python3-config --embed shows -lpython3.11 and maybe this command works also on Windows and it could show correct parameters

few days there was c - Cmd doesnt recognize Python.h, although i specified the path in the c_cpp_properties.json file - Stack Overflow where I show these commands in answer.

@furas hello, sorry for responding late but heres what happened with what you told me to do: when I did python3-config --include in system shell it opened a file with a bunch of text it gave me the exact position of the python3.11-config but I don't understand what to do with it.

it should show you one line with parameters - like -I/usr/include/python3.10 -I/usr/include/python3.10 - which you should add when you run g++ - like g++ ... -I/usr/include/python3.10 -I/usr/include/python3.10 .... And similar python3-config --ldflag  --embed should show line like -L/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.10 -lcrypt -ldl  -lm -lm and you should add it to line with g++

@furas I finaly decided to simply not use PyRun_SimpleStringFlags since I only want to execute a function but when I run "output.exe" it says "Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>" It seems like the problem is caused by Py_Initialize();
